# Modifying gradle task in a subproject

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, war, subproject, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

So, let's say I have this kind of project structure:

```
Root
    projA
        projA1-api
        projA2-core
        projA3-main
    projB
        projB1-api
        projB2-core
        projB3-main
    projC
        projC1-api
        projC2-core
        projC3-main
    and so on...
```

Some of the subprojects (the ones ending in "*-main*") have `war` and `spring boot` plugins applied to them, the root build.gradle file does not.
That means that projects *projA3-main, projB3-main* and *projC3-main* have the `bootWar` task which disables the `war` task.

Now, the problem lies within the fact that our jenkins pipeline builds wars by executing the `gradle war` command, which sucks and can't be changed.

So, what I want to do is to modify the war task in each of the subprojects containing the war plugin by setting it to depend on the `bootWar` task. I can do this by adding `war.dependsOn bootWar` into the subprojects' `build.gradle` files and that works, but I want to extract that code into the root `build.gradle`.

Also, I want the `war` task to also execute another task (let's call it `customPrintTask`) defined in the root `build.gradle` which just prints stuff into some file.

To summarize:

> Root build.gradle doesn't have, war, bootWar or Spring Boot plugins, but has the customPrintTask task
>
> "*-main*" subprojects have bootWar and spring boot plugins, and they also have the war plugin, but because I am using Spring Boot 2+ gradle plugin, the war task does not generate the war.

Basically, I want something like this:

```
allprojects {
    if (project.plugins.hasPlugin("war")) {
        war.dependsOn bootWar
        war.finalizedBy customPrintTask
    }
}
```

I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yo, figured it out.

```
allprojects {
    tasks.withType(War) {
        if (it.name != "bootWar") {
            dependsOn(customPrintTask)
            dependsOn(":" + it.project.name.replace("-main", "") + ":" + it.project.name + ":bootWar")
        }
    } 
}
```

I know no one cares, but this way I iterated over every task with the type `War` and if the tasks name is not `bootWar`(because of circular dependency) then depend on my custom print task and also depend on the `bootWar` task which is located in the subproject I am currently iterating over, which is the reason it looks dumb.

It's pretty simple, not sure how I missed this one...looks extremely ugly, but it works!